# install KODAMA package

Tags: r, machine-learning

I failed to install the package KODAMA.
My R version is 4.0.2.
I have tried two ways as below:

1.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("KODAMA", version = "1.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

2. 

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/KODAMA/KODAMA_1.5.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

But neither of them work. Is there a way to install KODAMA in R version 4.0.2?

To update, here is the error received:

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘KODAMA’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/KODAMA’
- restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/KODAMA’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/ln/s10_j4kx417glc637dcrstf40000gn/T//Rtmp3d0oDH/downloaded_packages/KODAMA_1.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: KODAMA has been removed from CRAN : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KODAMA/index.html You can try downloading it manually

Comment: The 2nd way should work; what exactly you get as output? Please update your post accordingly to include this info.

Comment: @BastienDucreux Hi! Could you explain how to install it manually?

Comment: @desertnaut Hi! I edited the post with the error I got.